# Webkit bug: elements appear on mouse event

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transforms

I'm using the carousel library [slick](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) to display different images and in each one i've put an absolute positioned description that it should shown on top of it. On firefox it works perfectly but in chrome and safari the description box doesn't show and only appears after I take the mouse out of the carousel button. You can see this happening here:

http://brandca.co/adsl/#vistas
(on the top left there's a menu button, go to "renders" and click the next slide button)

I've already tried to fix it putting z-index on the description div but didn't work.

Comment: Please post some code here, and/or a working minimal demo of the problem at http://jsfiddle.net or a similar site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote this library. Putting -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden on your .description div will fix this issue.

Comment: Btw, love your implementation of it. Looks awesome.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Love the library. Thanks for the compliment, means a lot coming from you. :)